# NSDictionary valueForKeyPath returns nill even the keypath exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

Here are 2 lines from my app. The first one works properly and I get the value "LE-05330" on the label but for the second one I get nil. What am I doing wrong for the second line?

```
//Working properly
self.lblSerialNo.text = [self.PartInfo valueForKeyPath:@"veri.parca_bilgisi.referans_no"];

//valueForKeyPath returns nil so label is empty.
self.lblCertNo.text = [self.PartInfo valueForKeyPath:@"veri.sertifika.sertifika_no"];
```

The JSON data on the self.PartInfo object is below;

```
{
    "durum": true,
    "hata": "",
    "veri": {
        "parca_bilgisi": {
            "imaj": "http://www.mywebsite.com:9898/mobapp/images/arac_hasar/arac-onsolkapi.jpg",
            "parca_tanimi": "ÖN SOL KAPI",
            "marka": "MYBRAND",
            "marka_kodu": "70",
            "model": "MYMODEL",
            "model_kodu": "?",
            "yil": "2005",
            "uretici": "MYManufacturer.",
            "referans_no": "LE-05330",
            "oem_no": "999999",
            "durum": "3",
            "durum_aciklama": "Transferred_to_Supplier"
        },
        "onarim_servis_bilgileri": {
            "servis_adi": "?",
            "iletisim_no": "?",
            "islem_tarihi": "?",
            "hasar_dosya_no": "?"
        },
        "sigorta_bilgileri": {
            "firma_adi": "?",
            "iletisim_no": "?",
            "ilgili_kisi": "?"
        },
        "eksper_bilgileri": {
            "onaylama_tarihi": "?"
        },
        "uretici_bilgileri": {
            "firma": "My Firm AS.",
            "imaj": "harita.jpg",
            "adres": "Carrer de Jacint Verdaguer, 58, 08970",
            "eposta": "myr@email.es",
            "tel": "+36 56565 345 317",
            "web": "www.styaasira.es",
            "kayit_tarihi": "7.7.2017 13:27:44",
            "durum": "3"
        },
        "sertifika": {
            "sertifikasyon_kurulusu": "87",
            "sertifika_no": "87",
            "gecerlilik_tarihi": "87"
        }
    }
}
```

My code to for retrieving NSDictionary (dict)

```
NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {       
        if (error == nil) {
            // Success
            NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                           JSONObjectWithData:data
                                           options:kNilOptions
                                           error:&error];
```

I eliminated the service call, and tried the same JSON as string, still no chance...

```
NSString *json = ...

    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                           error:&error];

    self.lblIssuer.text = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"veri.sertifika.sertifikasyon_kurulusu​"];
```

After several unsuccessful logical tries, I decided to focus on the data and tried to modify(simplfy) the JSON object and try to see if it works on different key names. So I first changed the name of the node from "sertifika" to "test" and the 3 sub node names to "a", "b" and "c". With this state I was able to get the value using valueForKeyPath. Then, I changed the name of the nodes back to original, and it also worked!!! Then I commented out reading JSON from constant string to service response,... wait for it... it also worked!!!....

Can anybody tell something logical about what was going on? Is there a some sort of hashing mechanism for the NSDictionary that had gone crazy? Anyway, changing the node names that fails and then back to original has solved my problem...

Comment: Can you try whether it is getting properly converted to NSData. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8xCW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8xCW.png)

Comment: What happens when you use this:
`NSDictionary * veri = PartInfo[@"veri"];
NSDictionary * sertifika = veri[@"sertifika"];
NSString * text = sertifika[@"sertifika_no"];
NSLog(@"text is %@", text);`

Comment: Can you update the code to show how you load the dictionary ? i tried the json above and it works fine for me. you have an issue somewhere else

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg just posted the loading code, but why is it working for other nodes but not "sertifika"?

Comment: @JohnnyRockex it works that way... But I need with valueForKeyPath

Comment: I tried you code (with `[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`, once I converted the `"` into `\"`), didn't get any issue.

Comment: You still didn't show how the data looks like before loading it, can you update your question to show exactly the full flow ?
the most important part is to see what is inside `NSString *json = ...`, answers cannot be given with such a trivial point missing :)

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg I posted the JSON string in my second update, the only difference is I used escape character for the ("). And the data is not string originally, its of type NSData, I posted the data for you to see the serialized string out of it.